# Why has my Help Center been reduced to this-'The selected topic is currently unavailable'?

Tags: macos

My iMac used to be a valuable information, and learning tool for me… then I made the fatal mistake of upgrading from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion. What a disaster! The Help Center and all other 'help' menus at some level end up with this message:

[image]

I have searched, and found that many other people have had the same problem. Some recon it is certain files like com.apple.helpd that have corrupted, others say it is due to a problem with ISP Satellite connections. Whatever it is, I haven't been able to fix it. A 'clean' re-install made no difference.

Apart from all the help menus on all applications fail as soon as it needs info from the internet, I have no problem using the internet at all with any other applications (Safari, Mail, etc.)

Does anyone have a definite answer that could fix this problem once and for all?

**Update:**

As requested by sameetandpotatoes in his answer, here is the relevant outputs of console.log:

```
21/08/13 5:23:29.328 PM helpd[643]: Could not find access page in directory /Applications/Debut.app/Contents/Resources/help
21/08/13 5:23:29.343 PM helpd[643]: Could not find access page in directory /Applications/Debut.app/Contents/Resources/help
21/08/13 5:23:31.199 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder[2962]) Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing
21/08/13 5:23:32.396 PM helpd[643]: Could not find access page in directory /Applications/SketchBookExpress.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Help
21/08/13 5:23:32.402 PM helpd[643]: Could not find access page in directory /Applications/SketchBookExpress.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Help
21/08/13 5:23:41.514 PM HelpViewer[2966]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:23:41.514 PM HelpViewer[2966]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:23:41.516 PM HelpViewer[2966]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:23:41.516 PM HelpViewer[2966]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:23:41.584 PM HelpViewer[2966]: No results found for anchor mh40612 in book com.apple.machelp
21/08/13 5:24:23.291 PM HelpViewer[2972]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:24:23.291 PM HelpViewer[2972]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:24:23.293 PM HelpViewer[2972]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:24:23.294 PM HelpViewer[2972]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:24:25.330 PM HelpViewer[2972]: No results found for anchor mh40612 in book com.apple.machelp
21/08/13 5:25:14.107 PM HelpViewer[2972]: nonModChar: q
21/08/13 5:25:25.805 PM HelpViewer[2983]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:25:25.805 PM HelpViewer[2983]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:25:25.807 PM HelpViewer[2983]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:25:25.808 PM HelpViewer[2983]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:25:25.838 PM HelpViewer[2983]: No results found for anchor mh40612 in book com.apple.machelp
21/08/13 5:25:29.406 PM HelpViewer[2983]: nonModChar: q
21/08/13 5:25:40.428 PM login[2985]: USER_PROCESS: 2985 ttys000
21/08/13 5:26:27.537 PM login[2985]: DEAD_PROCESS: 2985 ttys000
21/08/13 5:30:59.726 PM HelpViewer[2993]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:30:59.726 PM HelpViewer[2993]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:31:00.130 PM helpd[2998]: Could not find access page in directory /Applications/Debut.app/Contents/Resources/help
21/08/13 5:31:00.146 PM helpd[2998]: Could not find access page in directory /Applications/Debut.app/Contents/Resources/help
21/08/13 5:31:00.152 PM helpd[2998]: Could not find access page in directory /Applications/SketchBookExpress.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Help
21/08/13 5:31:00.158 PM helpd[2998]: Could not find access page in directory /Applications/SketchBookExpress.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Help
21/08/13 5:31:00.305 PM HelpViewer[2993]: nonModChar: q
21/08/13 5:31:00.306 PM HelpViewer[2993]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
21/08/13 5:31:00.306 PM HelpViewer[2993]: : event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. (line: 0)
```

Comment: If you create a new account and log in, does help work on that account?

Comment: @DanielLawson, wow, a response, thank you.:) I've never created a new account before so it will take me a little while to figure it out.

Comment: @DanielLawson, The answer is no, help doesn't work on the new account.

Comment: There's a free app called onyx that can be used to clear out your help cache and rebuild it.  Have you  tried something like that? http://www.titanium.free.fr/   If that doesn't work, then move onto network issues, dns, ports, firewall, etc.

Comment: Are you saying if you connect your Mac to the internet and can browse sites, when you enter "wallpaper" into the Finder help - it doesn't then download some articles locally and then show you between 2 and 15 articles?

Comment: @bmike, My internet connection works fine, the computer is permanently connected. The problem lies with the Help Menus of all applications, including Finder (regardless of whether I'm on the 'net' or not). Some local help info is available, but as soon as help is required from the internet, it comes up with the 'unavailable' message (see it in my question).

Answer (score 6):

### Reset Help center

Most Help Center problems are the result of corrupted Help Center cache or preferences files. The following steps should resolve such problems. Note that these instructions cover multiple versions of Mac OS X: you may have only some of the files or folders cited for deletion.

1. Close or quit `Help Center` if it is open.
2. Click the red Close button in the upper-left corner of the Help Center window.
3. Trash the following files in your Home > Library > Preferences folder, if they exist:

   ```
       com.apple.help.plist
       com.apple.helpd.plist
       com.apple.helpviewer.plist
   ```
4. Trash the following folders in your Home > Library > Caches folder, if they exist:

   ```
       com.apple.helpd folder
       com.apple.helpviewer folder
   ```
5. Empty the Trash. If you receive an alert stating that the Trash cannot be emptied "because the item Cache.db is in use," then terminate the helpd process using Activity Monitor. The helpd (help dameon) is a process that provides various services to Help Viewer.

### Next Step (if the above doesn't work)

Enable Help Center logging.

1. Quit (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) Help Viewer if it is open.
2. Launch Terminal, which is located in the Macintosh HD > Applications > Utilities folder.
3. At the Terminal prompt, copy this command:

   ```
    defaults write com.apple.helpviewer HelpViewerDebugging -bool YES
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Close Terminal or (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>).
6. Launch Help Center by selecting Finder > Help > Help Center. All Help Center actions will be logged in console.log, which you can access via Console. Note that Help Center logging will write a lot to the console.log.

Edit your question and include the relevant outputs of `console.log`.

---

---

### Update

Steve, I'm including this as an update because it would have been too long as a comment.

1. Do you have the OS X installer dmg for Snow Leopard or Mountain Lion? If yes, you could use [Pacifist](http://download.cnet.com/Pacifist/3000-2094_4-10135915.html) to extract files that are necessary for Help Center. (By "clean re-install", do you mean you wiped your computer and reinstalled the OS?)
2. In  regards to the `console.log`, the `event.layerX and event.layerY` has to do with jQuery for a web browser (Chrome I think?). I know that it is not related to the `Help Center` in any way. The first few lines:

   ```
    Could not find access page in directory /Applications/Debut.app/Contents/Resources/help 21/08/13 5:23:29.343 PM helpd[643]
   ```

mean that the `.help` files are missing in your applications (Debut and SketchbookExpress).

[This](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/helpviewer.html) is the best link I can find in regards to Help Center, although it is deprecated and meant for older versions (This is where I got the steps to reset `Help Center`. I've went through it already but take another look.

> Help books are installed in one of two ways:
>
> ```
> 1. Directly in the Macintosh HD > Library > Documentation > Help folder.
> 2. Distributed as part of an application's package file and contained within the package of the application for which the help book provides help information.
> ```

Check that file path and see if you have help books in Library => Documentation => Help. For instance, I have:

```
AppleScript.help - 859 KB
HelpCenter.help - 1.6 MB
MacHelp.help - 21.4 MB
VoiceOver.help- 1.4 MB
```

If you don't have those files, or they are empty or something, you may want to redownload those (This is where Pacifist might come in handy).

As for the second way that help books are installed, it seems that you are missing it for `Debut.app` and `SketchbookExpress.app`. I am not sure how you would resolve this, maybe reinstall the application? What happens if you redownload the application, `double click` and click `Show Package Contents` and then copy the `help` folder from the downloaded application to your installed application?

Comment: I was advised to do something very similar to this about 4 months ago - it had no effect. I'm prepared to try what you suggest, but I'm concerned about stuffing things up even more! :-[ How safe is it?

Comment: It is safe because it is just removing the cached version of it. When you open Help Center, it will rebuild the caches. Besides, it can't get any worse than what you already have :). Just remember to remove only the `plists` and folders that I specified, nothing else.

Comment: Reset Help Center didn't work so I have added the outputs of console.log to my question. It looks a bit of a mess! Note: This includes quitting Help Center.

Comment: SteveW, please see my update above.

Comment: I do have the installers for both Snow Leopard and Mountain Lion. Yes, I erased the entire hard drive before re-install. I do use Chrome. I don't use Debut or SketchbookExpress so their help files would probably become available if I was to open them again (this info would have been dumped when I reset the Help Center I think). I have exactly the same files as you in my Library > Documentation > Help folder. Thanks for all your help, but I don't think we are on the right track here so I am now seeking the help of an Apple technician.